# Update appmanifest capabilities, visual elements from cordova plugin windows 10

Tags: cordova, uwp, windows-10, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I need to update package.appmanifest for windows 10 app via cordova plugin using cmd line. 
Below is my code snippet in plugin.xml that should update the appmanifest but doesn't work.

```
  <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities">

     <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
     <DeviceCapability Name="microphone"/>

</config-file>
```

> Windows version: 4.4.3
>
> Cordova version: 6.4.0

Also please let me know how to change app icons? I have tried following but that also doesn't work.

```
 <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Applications/Application">

  <uap:VisualElements
    DisplayName="MyApp"
    Description="My description"
    BackgroundColor="#464646"
    Square150x150Logo="images\Square150x150Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="images\Square44x44Logo.png">

    <uap:SplashScreen Image="images\splashscreen.png" />
    <uap:DefaultTile ShortName="MyAppName"
                     Square310x310Logo="images\Square310x310Logo.png"
                     Square71x71Logo="images\Square71x71Logo.png"
                     Wide310x150Logo="images\Wide310x150Logo.png" />

  </uap:VisualElements>
</config-file>
```

**Update:**

I have also tried with putting target as ***target="package.windows10.appxmanifest"*** and that also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to update package.appmanifest for windows 10 app via cordova plugin using cmd line. Below is my code snippet in plugin.xml that should update the appmanifest but doesn't work.

Please make sure you have added `config-file` in the right place:

An Example of `plugin.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
       id="cordova-plugin-test"
  version="1.0.0">
<name>TestPlugin</name>
<description>Cordova Test Plugin</description>
<license>Apache 2.0</license>


<!-- windows -->
<platform name="windows">
    <config-file target="package.appxmanifest" parent="/Package/Capabilities">
        <Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
        <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    </config-file>
</platform>

</plugin>
```

Notes: After build, you can check the result in `platforms\windows\package.appxmanifest`.

> Also please let me know how to change app icons?

To change the app icons, please refer to [Customize app icons](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html#windows).

Comment: Hi Elvis Xia, I have config-file in the right place. But still my appxmanifest file is not updated. I have package.windows.appxmanifest, package.phone.appxmanifest and package.windows10.appxmanifest inside platforms\windows\ but no package.appxmanifest. Am I missing something?

Comment: The files are correct, it's strange that the manifest files are not updated. Could you check if the plugin is added correctly and is referenced in the` `config.xml` file  like `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-test" spec="~1.0.0" src="F:\WorkingSample\folder\TestPlugin" />`

Comment: Yes the plugin is installed. In config.xml,it is like: 
    `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-test" spec="E:\Desktop\SFApp\7.0_Development\Plugins_new\cordova-plugin-test" />`

Comment: Could you please share the test project? The issue is not reproduceable by my side.

Comment: Hi Elvis, I tried by creating a fresh project and seems it is working fine. Thank you for your effort. I will let you know if I face any issues regarding this. Voted up and marked as answer :)